# How to add particular value at start of each row, where not already present?

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula, concatenation

I have an Excel sheet containing website addresses, the records count nearly 3,000, and want to filter it so that duplicates can be removed. The problem is that many web addresses (almost 2,000 or so) in my Excel sheet start with `http`,  for example `http://www.google.com`, and the rest start without `http`. That means some what like this "google" now when I use Excel's filter command it removes only duplicates from same type of data, i.e. *either* with `http` or without `http` data.

I want to add `http` in all remaining 1,000 or so domains so that I can filter it using filter command.

Is there any command to add `http` in the starting value all 1,000 or so rows of sheet?

Answer (score 2):

Formula (assuming the addresses are in col A) for B1:

```
=IF(LEFT(LOWER(A1);7) = "http://"; A1; CONCATENATE("http://"; A1))
```

Or, if you're in a country that uses commas to separate function arguments:

```
=IF(LEFT(LOWER(A1), 7) = "http://", A1, CONCATENATE("http://", A1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a formula like this:

```
="http://"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://","")
```

Basically this is replacing the http to any string automatically if it does exist, at the same time as appending a fresh http:// on to it

Answer (score 0):

Say, if you have data like this

```
 A                 B
---------        ----------
xyz.com
http://abc.com
yyy.com
```

In column B, use a function similar to this.

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("http:",A1,1)),CONCATENATE("http://",A1),A1)
```

Drag down to fill.

This will put an http prefix for all items in A where the prefix doesn't exist. Tweak this a little bit for your specific case if needed.